# How to resolve "Verified publisher: Unknown" message while running the setup prgram

Tags: windows, security, installation, code-signing

When I try to install my software in some computers, I used to get a message "Verified publisher: Unknown". 
I understand from some documentation that the installer must be signed.

Question 1:
Can I sign the installer using  self-signed certificate ?
The self signed certficate displays " This certificate cannot be verified up to a trusted certification authority"

Please advice.

Comment: Self-signed certificate is good for testing only. You can install the certificate you used to sign into Trusted CAs, and Windows would trust it and would therefore display the publisher. Yet in the real world where you distribute the application you would rather buy a certificate so it's trusted on users' systems. In this case self-signed certificate can be used only to ensure the signed file wasn't modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, self-signed certificate won't work, as you have discovered. You need to purchase a "code signing certificate" (quoted for it's a term for you to search for) and sign-and-timestamp your EXE (most likely both setup and application files).